# pandasにて一次元へというエラーがでる

Tags: python, python3, pandas, numpy

```
array([[-1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  7,  0],
       [-1,  9, 10, 11, 12, 11, 13, 11, 14, 11, 15, 12, 16, 17, 18],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1, 19, 20, 19, 21, 22, 23, 23, 22, 24, 22,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

上記をpandasのDFにしようとすると以下のエラーがでます。
なぜでるのでしょうか。ちなみに、A=[上記同じ形での値]で実行するとエラーにならないです。

実行コード

```
statistic = pd.DataFrame({
    "label" : labels,
    "feature1" : features,
})
```

エラー内容

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-8de74a8845ff> in <module>
      5 statistic = pd.DataFrame({
      6     "label" : labels,
----> 7     "feature1" : features,
      8 })
      9 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    409             )
    410         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 411             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    412         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    413             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    255             arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    256         ]
--> 257     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    258 
    259 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
     80 
     81     # don't force copy because getting jammed in an ndarray anyway
---> 82     arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
     83 
     84     # from BlockManager perspective

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _homogenize(data, index, dtype)
    321                 val = lib.fast_multiget(val, oindex.values, default=np.nan)
    322             val = sanitize_array(
--> 323                 val, index, dtype=dtype, copy=False, raise_cast_failure=False
    324             )
    325 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
    727     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
    728         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
--> 729             raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")
    730         else:
    731             subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージにあるとおり、`labels`や`features`は1次元の配列データの必要があるからです。
[pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

> Examples
>   Constructing DataFrame from a dictionary.
>
> ```
> >>> d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
> >>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
> >>> df
>    col1  col2
> 0     1     3
> 1     2     4
> ```

例えばこんな風にすれば正常に通りますよ。

```
statistic = pd.DataFrame({
    "label" : ["labels"],
    "feature1" : ["features"],
})
```

こんな形になります。

```
>>> statistic
    label  feature1
0  labels  features
```

あるいはこんな風に`labels`や`features`を1次元の配列データの変数として定義するとか。

```
labels = [-1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  7,  0]
features = [-1,  9, 10, 11, 12, 11, 13, 11, 14, 11, 15, 12, 16, 17, 18]

statistic = pd.DataFrame({
    "label" : labels,
    "feature1" : features,
})
```

こちらはこうですね。

```
>>> statistic
    label  feature1
0      -1        -1
1       0         9
2       1        10
3       1        11
4       1        12
5       0        11
6       2        13
7       3        11
8       4        14
9       5        11
10      6        15
11      7        12
12      8        16
13      7        17
14      0        18
```

`A=`で正常に出来ているであろう形はこんなでしょうか？

```
A =   [[-1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  7,  0],
       [-1,  9, 10, 11, 12, 11, 13, 11, 14, 11, 15, 12, 16, 17, 18],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1, 19, 20, 19, 21, 22, 23, 23, 22, 24, 22,  0,  0,  0,  0]]
statistic = pd.DataFrame(A)
>>> statistic
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
0 -1   0   1   1   1   0   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   7   0
1 -1   9  10  11  12  11  13  11  14  11  15  12  16  17  18
2 -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3 -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4 -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5 -1  19  20  19  21  22  23  23  22  24  22   0   0   0   0
```

---

もしかすると実際にやりたいのは、`labels`に各列(横軸)、`features`に各行(縦軸)の名前(あるいは縦横が逆でも)が入っているDataFrameを作りたいのでしょうか？
その場合は、以下のようになると思います。

```
statistic = pd.DataFrame(A,
    columns=labels,
    index=features
)
```

とか、

```
statistic = pd.DataFrame(A,
    columns=features,
    index=labels
)
```

参考：
[pandas.DataFrameの構造とその作成方法](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-dataframe-values-columns-index/)

> ```
> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4),
>                   columns=['col_0', 'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'],
>                   index=['row_0', 'row_1', 'row_2'])
>
> print(df)
> #        col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3
> # row_0      0      1      2      3
> # row_1      4      5      6      7
> # row_2      8      9     10     11
> ```

---

**追加質問に対して**
例えば：

```
statistic = pd.DataFrame(A)
```

と

```
statistic = pd.DataFrame(features)
```

なら同じ扱いとなります。

`features`をデータとして、`labels`を列名として扱いたいなら、以下のようになります。

```
labels = ['C0','C1','C2','C3','C4','C5']
features = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
            [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
            [19, 20 ,21, 22, 23, 24],
            [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]

statistic = pd.DataFrame(features,
    columns=labels
)
```

結果はこうなります。

```
>>> statistic
   C0  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   7   8   9  10  11  12
2  13  14  15  16  17  18
3  19  20  21  22  23  24
4  25  26  27  28  29  30
```

---

ただ、@metropolisさんのコメントも微妙に違うような？
こんな結果になるようですが、これが望んだ形なのでしょうか？
それとも使い方が悪いのでしょうか？

```
>>> statistic = pd.DataFrame({'feature1': iter(features)})
>>> statistic
                   feature1
0        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1     [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
2  [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
3  [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
4  [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

Comment: 回答有難うございます。1点確認したいのですが、以下は違うものでしょうか。

Comment: 皆様回答いただきまして有難うございます。
参考にさせて頂きました。もう少し私自身も勉強が必要に思いました。

Answer (score 0):

以下の同じfeaturesですが、何が違うのでしょうか。

```
array([[-1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  7,  0],
       [-1,  9, 10, 11, 12, 11, 13, 11, 14, 11, 15, 12, 16, 17, 18],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1, 19, 20, 19, 21, 22, 23, 23, 22, 24, 22,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

```
features = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],\
            [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],\
            [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],\
            [19, 20 ,21, 22, 23, 24],\
            [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]
```

Comment: numpy.array 型のオブジェクトだからです。上のオブジェクトを `a` とすると、`pd.DataFrame({'feature1': iter(a)})` とすれば同様の結果が得られます。

Comment: 参考までに、numpy.array 型のオブジェクトの場合は[ここ](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.25.x/pandas/core/internals/construction.py#L727)で、リスト型の場合は[ここ](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.25.x/pandas/core/internals/construction.py#L676)でデータのチェックが行われます。イテレータにしておけば `ndim == 1` というチェックをパスできる、という事です。

Comment: @tabo0073 さん、ちなみに追加の質問は元の質問を「編集」して追記してください。ここは掲示板では無く、回答欄は回答を書くところです。よろしくお願いします。あと、データの断片ではなく、元データをどう作ったか、どのようにDataFrameに入れたか、最終的に欲しいDataFrameは何か、といったことを追記してくれれば、回答者がいろいろ推測することが減って、的確な回答になりやすいです。